# How to make Bullet initiate from the direction the player is in

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am making 2D game in Unity.

In this I wanted to add a bullet with a limited number of shots.

The bullet fires in the direction in which the player is but always initiate from the right side even if the player is facing left side. And I have limited the bullet count to 3.

How do I put delay in between the occurrence of the bullets?

1st Script (Bullet)

```
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour {

    private Player player;
    public float speed = 1f;
    public int abc = 2;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        player = GameObject.Find ("Player").GetComponent<Player> ();
        if (player.aa.x == transform.localScale.x)
            abc = 1;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Update () {
        if (abc == 1)
            rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector3 (transform.localScale.x, 0, 1) * speed;
        else
            rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector3 (transform.localScale.x, 0, 1) * speed;
    }
}
```

2nd Script (Player)

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 10f;
    public Vector2 maxVelocity = new Vector2(3, 5);
    public bool standing;
    public float jetSpeed = 15f;
    public float airSpeedMultiplier = .3f;
    public AudioClip leftFootSound;
    public AudioClip rightFootSound;
    public AudioClip thudSound;
    public AudioClip rocketSound;
    public Vector3 aa = new Vector3(1,1,1);

    private Animator animator;
    private PlayerController controller;

    void Start(){
        controller = GetComponent<PlayerController> ();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    }

    void PlayLeftFootSound(){
        if (leftFootSound)
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint (leftFootSound, transform.position);
    }

    void PlayRightFootSound(){
        if (rightFootSound)
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint (rightFootSound, transform.position);
    }

    void PlayRocketSound(){
        if (!rocketSound || GameObject.Find ("RocketSound"))
            return;

        GameObject go = new GameObject ("RocketSound");
        AudioSource aSrc = go.AddComponent<AudioSource> ();
        aSrc.clip = rocketSound;
        aSrc.volume = 0.7f;
        aSrc.Play ();

        Destroy (go, rocketSound.length);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D target){
        if (!standing) {
            var absVelX = Mathf.Abs(rigidbody2D.velocity.x);
            var absVelY = Mathf.Abs(rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

            if(absVelX <= .1f || absVelY <= .1f){
                if(thudSound)
                    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(thudSound, transform.position);
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        var forceX = 0f;
        var forceY = 0f;

        var absVelX = Mathf.Abs (rigidbody2D.velocity.x);
        var absVelY = Mathf.Abs (rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

        if (absVelY < .2f)
            standing = true;
        else
            standing = false;

        if (controller.moving.x != 0) {
            if (absVelX < maxVelocity.x) {

                forceX = standing ? speed * controller.moving.x : (speed * controller.moving.x * airSpeedMultiplier);

                aa = transform.localScale = new Vector3 (forceX > 0 ? 1 : -1, 1, 1);

            }

            animator.SetInteger ("AnimState", 1);

        } else {
            animator.SetInteger ("AnimState", 0);
        }

        if (controller.moving.y > 0) {
            PlayRocketSound();
                        if (absVelY < maxVelocity.y)
                                forceY = jetSpeed * controller.moving.y;

                        animator.SetInteger ("AnimState", 2);
                } else if (absVelY > 0) {
            animator.SetInteger("AnimState", 3);
                }

        rigidbody2D.AddForce (new Vector2 (forceX, forceY));
    }
}
```

3rd Script (PlayerController)

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public Vector2 moving = new Vector2();
    public int Bulletlimit = 0;
    public int MaxBulletlimit = 3;
    public float bulletDelay = 3f;
    public bool Gun;

    public Bullet bullet;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {}

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        moving.x = moving.y = 0;

        if (Input.GetKey ("right")) {
            moving.x = 1;
        } else if (Input.GetKey ("left")) {
            moving.x = -1;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey ("up")) {
            moving.y = 1;
        } else if (Input.GetKey ("down")) {
            moving.y = -1;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey ("s")) {
            if(Gun){
                if(Bulletlimit < MaxBulletlimit)
                {
                    Bullet clone = Instantiate (bullet, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as Bullet;
                    Bulletlimit = Bulletlimit + 1;
                }
            }
        }   
    }

    public void BulletCount() {
        Bulletlimit = Bulletlimit - 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) There is an easy method to know where to position your bullets and which direction to shoot. Add a child dummy gameobject under your character that will be used as bullet's initial position. Position it where you want. Now this gameobject moves and rotates relative to your character. Use it's `transform.position` and `transform.rotation.forward` when you instantiate bullets.

2) Keep current time when user fired a bullet in a variable like `private float lastShotTime;`. Update it's value when you fired a bullet `lastShotTime = Time.time`. Then when user wants to shoot another bullet, check if enough time has passed since last shot `if (Time.time > lastShotTime + fireDelay) { Shoot(); }`.

Comment: I got the bullet delay thing correctly but getting a argument exception that get_time can only be called from the main thread and in the position one, I am not able to find the current side which the player is facing and getting a

Comment: Got the exception removed by placing the Time.time within a function but don't know why it needs to be done.